# How languagecookiename is related to "nop.installation.lang" in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce-3.90

I am getting issues that in nopcommerce 3.90 how languagecookiename is related to the "nop.installation.lang" string which is in InstallationLocalizationService class file.

For more let take one demo i.e. in nopcommerce in InstallationLocalizationService class file there is a LanguageCookieName is used which is coming in above line

```
private const string LanguageCookieName = "nop.installation.lang";
```

this languagecookiename showing their value i.e. "en"

but in the place of "nop.installation.lang" if I write anything then it shows their value is null.

For example:

```
private const string LanguageCookieName = "abc";
```

For that's why just I want to know that how "nop.installation.lang" is related to the const string LanguageCookieName.